# How do you send cron output to null and errors to email?

Tags: linux, bash

I have one cron job where I want to send its output to `/dev/null` but in case an error happens then it should send an email.

Otherwise I get an email daily of the output of cron and it's difficult for me to see when errors occured or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
59 23 * * * { tmpFile=/tmp/yourCmdErrs.$$ ; export tmpFile ; yourCommand > /dev/null 2>${tmpFile}; if [ -s ${tmpFile} ] ; then mailx -s"errors in yourCommand" < ${tmpFile} ; /bin/rm ${tmpFile} ; fi ; }
```

Exploded, it is

```
# set whatevery your time/days are # 59 23 * * * 
# my superstition to use open and closing # { }
# set a tmpFile var # tmpFile=/tmp/yourCmdErrs.$$ ; export tmpFile ;
# run yourCmd save STDERR to file # yourCommand > /dev/null 2>${tmpFile}; 
# check if tmpFile has anything in it # if [ -s ${tmpFile} ] ; then 
# obvious, hopefully # mailx -s"errors in yourCommand" < ${tmpFile} 
#  cleanup tmpFile # /bin/rm ${tmpFile} ;
#  fi 
# note that closing ';' is a must when using {} pairs ; }
```

The actual call to mail/mailx may be slightly funky, I don't have a way to test it right now.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Would suggest you simply modify the output of the scripts you are calling from cron to pipe *stdout* to /dev/null: all output goes to /dev/null, and *stderr* goes to the MAILTO target.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_program 2>&1 1>/dev/null | mailx -s "Subject" recipient ...
```

Although counter-intuitive (to me), redirections seems to be handled by the shell from right to left. This sequence first throws away stdout *then* redirects stderr to stdout.